# Unsupported operation workaround

Tags: tensorflow2.0, google-cloud-tpu

I have a custom layer which uses `tf.py_function` with some python code. Since this isn't supported by Cloud TPU, is it possible to place the computation for this layer on a CPU or GPU device? Or is the only solution to rewrite the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This use case is not currently supported.